# How to import several R packages inside a function I created?

Tags: r

I have this function that is meant to install and load several packages in order to run the whole script in one go.
But from what I can see the packages are only being loaded every other time, sometimes the function just installs them but doesn't load.
How can I solve this? Thank you so much in advance for any response.

```
install_load_packages=function(packages){
  install.packages(c("data.table","rentrez","worms","bold","stringr","readr","fingerprint","seqRFLP","dplyr","ggplot2"))
  library(seqRFLP)
  library(bold)
  library(data.table)
  library(rentrez)
  library(worms)
  library(stringr)
  library(readr)
  library(fingerprint)
  library(dplyr)
  library(ggplot2)
}
install_load_packages(packages)
```

Comment: A few questions..... why do you have a packages parameter if you just overwrite that object immediately? Why do you have that object when you don't ever actually use it?  What do you mean by the packages are only being loaded every other time?

Comment: `install.packages(packages); lapply(packages, library)`

Comment: Use `pacman` package: `pacman::p_load(data.table, bold, worms)`

Comment: yeah, I kinda forget to kemove that vector called packages, sorry I'm gonna edit

Comment: Hi I tried lapply but it returns  Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : 'package' must be of length 1

Comment: Did you find your answer?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to code it yourself you may use something like:

```
load.libraries <- c("data.table","rentrez","worms","bold","stringr","readr","fingerprint","seqRFLP","dplyr","ggplot2")
install.lib <- load.libraries[!load.libraries %in% installed.packages()]
for(libs in install.lib) install.packages(libs, dependences = TRUE)
sapply(load.libraries, require, character = TRUE)
```

If you prefere to use pacman packages (as I would recommend) you may use it like this:

```
if (!require("pacman")) install.packages("pacman")
packages <- c("data.table","rentrez","worms","bold","stringr","readr","fingerprint","seqRFLP","dplyr","ggplot2")
pacman::p_load(char = packages)
```